# SpriteKit - Random Movement

Tags: random, sprite-kit, skaction

I have a node that i want to move by random value, do something and then move again by another random value. here is my code:

```
    var randomValues = [250, 300, 90, 130]

    var randomSpace = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(randomValues.count)))
    var move =  SKAction.moveByX(randomSpace, y: 0, duration: 2)

    myNode.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([move, doSomething])))
```

When i type a fixed CGFloat value it works fine but it's fixed(Obviously), but when i tell it to move by `randomSpace` it doesn't move, it just makes all the action at the same place.

How i can i make it move at a random value each time ?

Answer (score 0):

This creates a value in the range 0 to 3 therefore the movement will not be to the same location, but they're very close together so you probably didn't notice the variation:

```
var randomSpace = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(randomValues.count)))
```

I think what you actually wanted to do is to generate a random index, then use the random index to get one of the randomValues:

```
var randomIndex = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(randomValues.count)))
var randomSpace = randomValues[randomIndex]
```

Comment: Works but not completely, it does pick a random value from my array, but it never changes it. whatever values it chooses randomly becomes fixed value. i need the value of the move action changes everytime during the game.

Comment: In that case you can't just repeat forever, you'd have to add a runBlock action at the end of the sequence that creates a new sequence with a new random location.